# Установка цвета текста

Tags: html, css

У меня не получается сделать цвет текста. Пишу вот такой скрипт:

```
<td style="color:#ee0000">текст </td>
```

У меня всё равно показывает "черный" цвет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><div style="color:#ee0000;"> текст </div></td>
```

Comment: спс заработало!

Comment: если ответ правильный, просьба отмечать его как верный, галочка на ответе